# Is it able to retrieve website content by Crawler4j?

Tags: java, parsing, web-crawler, jsoup, crawler4j

I m very new to Java.

Now , I want to retrieve the news article contents using Google news search -keyword: "toy" from page 1 to page 10.

https://www.google.com/search?q=toy&biw=1366&bih=645&tbm=nws&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTp82syoXPAhUMkpQKHawZBOoQ_AUICygE

That is retrieving 100 news content from page 1 - page 10. (assuming 10 news article in every pages)

After I read this 
[Crawler4j vs. Jsoup for the pages crawling and parsing in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888510/crawler4j-vs-jsoup-for-the-pages-crawling-and-parsing-in-java/34892537#34892537)

I decide to use Crawler4j as it can

> > Give base URI (home page)
> >
> > Take all the URIs from each page and retrieve the contents of those
> >     too.
> >
> > Move recursively for every URI you  retrieve.
> >
> > Retrieve the contents only of URIs that are inside this website (there
> >     could be
> >     external URIs referencing another website, we  don't need those).

In my case , I can give the google search page from p1 to p10 .And it returns the 100 news article if I set `intnumberOfCrawlers=1`

---

However , when i try the Quickstart of Crawler4j [example](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j)

It only returns the external links found from the orginal link .
Like these:

```
    URL: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~lopes/
Text length: 2619
Html length: 11656
Number of outgoing links: 38
URL: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/
Text length: 4503
Html length: 23713
Number of outgoing links: 24
URL: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/courses.html
Text length: 2222
Html length: 15138
Number of outgoing links: 33
URL: http://www.ics.uci.edu/
Text length: 3661
Html length: 51628
Number of outgoing links: 86
```

---

**Hence , I wonder can `crawler4j` perform the function I raised . Or should I use `crawler4j` +`JSoup`together ?**

Answer (score 4):

`crawler4j` respects crawler politness such as the [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org/). In your case this file is the following [one](https://www.google.com/robots.txt).

Inspecting this file reveals, that it is disallowed to crawl your given seed points:

```
 Disallow: /search
```

So you won't be able to crawl the given site, unless you modify the [classes](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/tree/master/crawler4j/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/robotstxt) to ignore `robots.txt`. However, this is not considered polite and is not compliant with crawler ethics.

Comment: polite my ass, got an updated link for disabling robots.txt?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of questions on your post I will try my best to answer:

**"Is it able to retrieve website content by Crawler4j?"**

1. Yes it can as demonstrated by the example on the github source code
2. However for for more advance DOM parsing/manipulation I will encourage you to add Jsoup. Here is the documentation for [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)

**"Hence , I wonder can crawler4j perform the function I raised . Or should I use crawler4j +JSouptogether ?"**

1. Use Crawler4j for what it is great at most, Crawling
2. Use Jsoup for extracting and manipulating data via a convenient API

**"It only returns the external links found from the orginal link . Like these"**

- In the `BasicCrawler` you'll need to add the allow urls here `return href.startsWith("http://www.ics.uci.edu/");` modify to include more
- In the `BasicCrawlController` you'll need to add your page seeds here `config.setMaxDepthOfCrawling(2);`